# $500 PAYPAL CASH BONUS TONIGHT to the first one who can explain this picture to me

Tags: color

[image]"Okay, let's try **cash."**  Because I've got it.  Here is a picture of Tom Hanks.  On my screen it is entirely gray.  No color at all.  On my fairly-recent Macbook Pro, every image or movie that I see, whether on a web page or in Final Cut, shows up in more-or-less this gray and this compression.  Regardless of what "color profile" I select in the *Displays* control panel.

My Mac is current, the OS is current, and this whole thing started happening to me about three weeks ago.

Be the first one to come up with the answer that I seek, and the ***==ca$h==*** is yours via PayPal.

But, you've got to first present your answer, acceptable to me, on this forum - publicly.  No brownie-points for you if you say it doesn't look wrong to you. Your task is to explain to me why it looks wrong to *me,* and what I can right-now do about it.

Answer (score 3):

Try looking in your System Preferences -> Accessibility -> Display.

You might have "Use Greyscale" selected.

If this is right, donate the money to a good cause.

Comment: I seriously doubt if this is the root cause of the issue as the OP would have stated that everything is gray, which he didn't, just the picture of Tom Hanks is gray by his description.  BTW In **macOS Catalina** and **macOS Big Sur** there is no "Use Greyscale" at "System Preferences -> Accessibility -> Display".